# C++ DLL Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

so I started studying C++, and I got a weird problem with pointers and address, I am trying to get the address of an object, This works:
(The DLL is injected into Win7's Minesweeper)

```
CBase base = *(CBase*)(*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4));
CGame game = *(CGame*)base.msGame;
std::cout << std::hex << (*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4)) <<    std::endl
```

I thought the following should give me the same address, the begging of CBase, but it gives me some weird address:

```
CBase base = *(CBase*)(*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4));
CGame game = *(CGame*)base.msGame;
std::cout << std::hex << &base << std::endl;
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Consider `int i = 0, b = *(&i); std::cout << &i << " " << &b;`

Comment: Side note: I think injecting C++ code into a random process is not necessary the best way to "start studying C++" (or any language with its own runtime...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an address:

```
(*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4))
```

Then it is dereferenced:

```
*(CBase*)(*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4))
```

Then the dereferenced object (not its address) is assigned to a local variable `base`.

```
CBase base = *(CBase*)(*(__int32*)((DWORD)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll + 0x00868B4));
```

So the dereferenced object and `base` has the same value, but they do not have the same address.

Comment: omg I just realized how basic this is, and I actually know all of that. Probably cause I worked on this thing at 05:00 AM in the morning. Anyway thanks!